# The form of code difference between Oracle and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I was converting codes in Oracle to MYSQL via http://www.sqlines.com/online. The codes are perfectly correct in Oracle(Tables and data created without any error message), but when I copy the codes and paste to MYSQL there is error message :

> SQL Error [1005] [HY000]: Can't create table `universityddl`.`faculty` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed").

I can not figure out what is the reason because I am new to DBMS. I appreciate if anybody can help.

Code in Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty ( 
    FacNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL, 
    FacFirstName  VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    FacLastName   VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    FacCity       VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    FacState      CHAR(2)       NOT NULL, 
    FacDept       CHAR(6)       NULL, 
    FacRank       CHAR(4)       NULL, 
    FacSalary     DECIMAL(10,2) NULL, 
    FacSupervisor CHAR(11)      NULL, 
    FacHireDate   DATE      NULL, 
    FacZipCode    CHAR(10)      NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT FacultyPK PRIMARY KEY (FacNo),  
    CONSTRAINT SupervisorFK FOREIGN KEY (FacSupervisor) REFERENCES Faculty
);

CREATE TABLE Course ( 
    CourseNo      CHAR(6)       NOT NULL, 
    CrsDesc       VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL, 
    CrsUnits      INTEGER       NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT CoursePK PRIMARY KEY (CourseNo) 
);

CREATE TABLE Offering ( 
    OfferNo       INTEGER       NOT NULL, 
    CourseNo      CHAR(6)       NOT NULL, 
    OffTerm       CHAR(6)       NOT NULL, 
    OffYear       INTEGER       NOT NULL, 
    OffLocation   VARCHAR(30)   NULL, 
    OffTime       VARCHAR(10)   NULL, 
    FacNo         CHAR(11)      NULL, 
    OffDays       CHAR(4)       NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT OfferingPK PRIMARY KEY (OfferNo), 
    CONSTRAINT CourseFK FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course, 
    CONSTRAINT FacultyFK FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) REFERENCES Faculty
);

CREATE TABLE Student ( 
    StdNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL, 
    StdFirstName  VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    StdLastName   VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    StdCity       VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    StdState      CHAR(2)       NOT NULL, 
    StdZip        CHAR(10)      NOT NULL, 
    StdMajor      CHAR(6)       NULL, 
    StdClass      CHAR(2)       NULL, 
    StdGPA        DECIMAL(3,2)  NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT StudentPk PRIMARY KEY (StdNo) 
);

CREATE TABLE Enrollment( 
    OfferNo       INTEGER       NOT NULL, 
    StdNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL, 
    EnrGrade      DECIMAL(3,2)  NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT EnrollmentPK PRIMARY KEY (OfferNo,StdNo), 
    CONSTRAINT OfferingFK FOREIGN KEY (OfferNo) REFERENCES Offering 
                      ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT StudentFK FOREIGN KEY (StdNo) REFERENCES Student 
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('543210987','VICTORIA','EMMANUEL','BOTHELL','WA','MS','PROF',120000.0,NULL,'15/Apr/1998','98011-2242');

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('654321098','LEONARD','FIBON','SEATTLE','WA','MS','ASSC',70000.00,'543210987','1/May/1996','98121-0094');

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('098765432','LEONARD','VINCE','SEATTLE','WA','MS','ASST',35000.00,'654321098','10/Apr/1997','98111-9921');

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('765432109','NICKI','MACON','BELLEVUE','WA','FIN','PROF',65000.00,NULL,'11/Apr/1999','98015-9945');

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('876543210','CRISTOPHER','COLAN','SEATTLE','WA','MS','ASST',40000.00,'654321098','1/Mar/2001','98114-1332');

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('987654321','JULIA','MILLS','SEATTLE','WA','FIN','ASSC',75000.00,'765432109','15/Mar/2002','98114-9954');

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('FIN300','FUNDAMENTALS OF FINANCE',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('FIN450','PRINCIPLES OF INVESTMENTS',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('FIN480','CORPORATE FINANCE',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('IS320','FUNDAMENTALS OF BUSINESS PROGRAMMING',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('IS460','SYSTEMS ANALYSIS',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('IS470','BUSINESS DATA COMMUNICATIONS',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('IS480','FUNDAMENTALS OF DATABASE MANAGEMENT',4);

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (1111,'IS320','SUMMER',2010,'BLM302','10:30:00',NULL,'MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (1234,'IS320','FALL',2009,'BLM302','10:30:00','098765432','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (2222,'IS460','SUMMER',2009,'BLM412','13:30:00',NULL,'TTH');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (3333,'IS320','SPRING',2010,'BLM214','8:30:00','098765432','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (4321,'IS320','FALL',2009,'BLM214','15:30:00','098765432','TTH');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (4444,'IS320','WINTER',2010,'BLM302','15:30:00','543210987','TTH');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (5555,'FIN300','WINTER',2010,'BLM207','8:30:00','765432109','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (5678,'IS480','WINTER',2010,'BLM302','10:30:00','987654321','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (5679,'IS480','SPRING',2010,'BLM412','15:30:00','876543210','TTH');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (6666,'FIN450','WINTER',2010,'BLM212','10:30:00','987654321','TTH');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (7777,'FIN480','SPRING',2010,'BLM305','13:30:00','765432109','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (8888,'IS320','SUMMER',2010,'BLM405','13:30:00','654321098','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (9876,'IS460','SPRING',2010,'BLM307','13:30:00','654321098','TTH');

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('123456789','HOMER','WELLS','SEATTLE','WA','98121-1111','IS','FR',3.00);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('124567890','BOB','NORBERT','BOTHELL','WA','98011-2121','FIN','JR',2.70);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('234567890','CANDY','KENDALL','TACOMA','WA','99042-3321','ACCT','JR',3.50);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('345678901','WALLY','KENDALL','SEATTLE','WA','98123-1141','IS','SR',2.80);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('456789012','JOE','ESTRADA','SEATTLE','WA','98121-2333','FIN','SR',3.20);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('567890123','MARIAH','DODGE','SEATTLE','WA','98114-0021','IS','JR',3.60);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('678901234','TESS','DODGE','REDMOND','WA','98116-2344','ACCT','SO',3.30);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('789012345','ROBERTO','MORALES','SEATTLE','WA','98121-2212','FIN','JR',2.50);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('876543210','CRISTOPHER','COLAN','SEATTLE','WA','98114-1332','IS','SR',4.00);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('890123456','LUKE','BRAZZI','SEATTLE','WA','98116-0021','IS','SR',2.20);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('901234567','WILLIAM','PILGRIM','BOTHELL','WA','98113-1885','IS','SO',3.80);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'123456789',3.30);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'234567890',3.50);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'345678901',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'456789012',3.10);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'567890123',3.80);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'678901234',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'123456789',3.50);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'124567890',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'789012345',3.50);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'876543210',3.10);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'890123456',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'901234567',3.10);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5555,'123456789',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5555,'124567890',2.70);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5678,'123456789',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5678,'234567890',2.80);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5678,'345678901',3.30);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5678,'456789012',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5678,'567890123',2.60);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'123456789',2.00);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'124567890',3.70);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'678901234',3.30);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'789012345',3.80);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'890123456',2.90);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'901234567',3.10);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (6666,'234567890',3.10);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (6666,'567890123',3.60);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (7777,'876543210',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (7777,'890123456',3.70);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (7777,'901234567',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'124567890',3.50);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'234567890',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'345678901',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'456789012',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'567890123',2.60);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'678901234',3.30);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'901234567',4.00);
```

Code after converted(to MY SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty ( 
    FacNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL, 
    FacFirstName  VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    FacLastName   VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    FacCity       VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    FacState      CHAR(2)       NOT NULL, 
    FacDept       CHAR(6)       NULL, 
    FacRank       CHAR(4)       NULL, 
    FacSalary     DECIMAL(10,2) NULL, 
    FacSupervisor CHAR(11)      NULL, 
    FacHireDate   DATE      NULL, 
    FacZipCode    CHAR(10)      NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT FacultyPK PRIMARY KEY (FacNo),  
    CONSTRAINT SupervisorFK FOREIGN KEY (FacSupervisor) REFERENCES Faculty
);

CREATE TABLE Course ( 
    CourseNo      CHAR(6)       NOT NULL, 
    CrsDesc       VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL, 
    CrsUnits      INTEGER       NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT CoursePK PRIMARY KEY (CourseNo) 
);

CREATE TABLE Offering ( 
    OfferNo       INTEGER       NOT NULL, 
    CourseNo      CHAR(6)       NOT NULL, 
    OffTerm       CHAR(6)       NOT NULL, 
    OffYear       INTEGER       NOT NULL, 
    OffLocation   VARCHAR(30)   NULL, 
    OffTime       VARCHAR(10)   NULL, 
    FacNo         CHAR(11)      NULL, 
    OffDays       CHAR(4)       NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT OfferingPK PRIMARY KEY (OfferNo), 
    CONSTRAINT CourseFK FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course, 
    CONSTRAINT FacultyFK FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) REFERENCES Faculty
);

CREATE TABLE Student ( 
    StdNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL, 
    StdFirstName  VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    StdLastName   VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    StdCity       VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL, 
    StdState      CHAR(2)       NOT NULL, 
    StdZip        CHAR(10)      NOT NULL, 
    StdMajor      CHAR(6)       NULL, 
    StdClass      CHAR(2)       NULL, 
    StdGPA        DECIMAL(3,2)  NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT StudentPk PRIMARY KEY (StdNo) 
);

CREATE TABLE Enrollment( 
    OfferNo       INTEGER       NOT NULL, 
    StdNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL, 
    EnrGrade      DECIMAL(3,2)  NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT EnrollmentPK PRIMARY KEY (OfferNo,StdNo), 
    CONSTRAINT OfferingFK FOREIGN KEY (OfferNo) REFERENCES Offering 
                      ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT StudentFK FOREIGN KEY (StdNo) REFERENCES Student 
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('543210987','VICTORIA','EMMANUEL','BOTHELL','WA','MS','PROF',120000.0,NULL,'15/Apr/1998','98011-2242');

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('654321098','LEONARD','FIBON','SEATTLE','WA','MS','ASSC',70000.00,'543210987','1/May/1996','98121-0094');

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('098765432','LEONARD','VINCE','SEATTLE','WA','MS','ASST',35000.00,'654321098','10/Apr/1997','98111-9921');

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('765432109','NICKI','MACON','BELLEVUE','WA','FIN','PROF',65000.00,NULL,'11/Apr/1999','98015-9945');

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('876543210','CRISTOPHER','COLAN','SEATTLE','WA','MS','ASST',40000.00,'654321098','1/Mar/2001','98114-1332');

INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES ('987654321','JULIA','MILLS','SEATTLE','WA','FIN','ASSC',75000.00,'765432109','15/Mar/2002','98114-9954');

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('FIN300','FUNDAMENTALS OF FINANCE',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('FIN450','PRINCIPLES OF INVESTMENTS',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('FIN480','CORPORATE FINANCE',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('IS320','FUNDAMENTALS OF BUSINESS PROGRAMMING',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('IS460','SYSTEMS ANALYSIS',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('IS470','BUSINESS DATA COMMUNICATIONS',4);

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('IS480','FUNDAMENTALS OF DATABASE MANAGEMENT',4);

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (1111,'IS320','SUMMER',2010,'BLM302','10:30:00',NULL,'MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (1234,'IS320','FALL',2009,'BLM302','10:30:00','098765432','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (2222,'IS460','SUMMER',2009,'BLM412','13:30:00',NULL,'TTH');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (3333,'IS320','SPRING',2010,'BLM214','8:30:00','098765432','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (4321,'IS320','FALL',2009,'BLM214','15:30:00','098765432','TTH');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (4444,'IS320','WINTER',2010,'BLM302','15:30:00','543210987','TTH');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (5555,'FIN300','WINTER',2010,'BLM207','8:30:00','765432109','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (5678,'IS480','WINTER',2010,'BLM302','10:30:00','987654321','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (5679,'IS480','SPRING',2010,'BLM412','15:30:00','876543210','TTH');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (6666,'FIN450','WINTER',2010,'BLM212','10:30:00','987654321','TTH');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (7777,'FIN480','SPRING',2010,'BLM305','13:30:00','765432109','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (8888,'IS320','SUMMER',2010,'BLM405','13:30:00','654321098','MW');

INSERT INTO Offering VALUES (9876,'IS460','SPRING',2010,'BLM307','13:30:00','654321098','TTH');

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('123456789','HOMER','WELLS','SEATTLE','WA','98121-1111','IS','FR',3.00);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('124567890','BOB','NORBERT','BOTHELL','WA','98011-2121','FIN','JR',2.70);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('234567890','CANDY','KENDALL','TACOMA','WA','99042-3321','ACCT','JR',3.50);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('345678901','WALLY','KENDALL','SEATTLE','WA','98123-1141','IS','SR',2.80);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('456789012','JOE','ESTRADA','SEATTLE','WA','98121-2333','FIN','SR',3.20);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('567890123','MARIAH','DODGE','SEATTLE','WA','98114-0021','IS','JR',3.60);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('678901234','TESS','DODGE','REDMOND','WA','98116-2344','ACCT','SO',3.30);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('789012345','ROBERTO','MORALES','SEATTLE','WA','98121-2212','FIN','JR',2.50);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('876543210','CRISTOPHER','COLAN','SEATTLE','WA','98114-1332','IS','SR',4.00);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('890123456','LUKE','BRAZZI','SEATTLE','WA','98116-0021','IS','SR',2.20);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('901234567','WILLIAM','PILGRIM','BOTHELL','WA','98113-1885','IS','SO',3.80);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'123456789',3.30);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'234567890',3.50);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'345678901',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'456789012',3.10);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'567890123',3.80);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (1234,'678901234',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'123456789',3.50);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'124567890',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'789012345',3.50);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'876543210',3.10);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'890123456',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (4321,'901234567',3.10);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5555,'123456789',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5555,'124567890',2.70);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5678,'123456789',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5678,'234567890',2.80);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5678,'345678901',3.30);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5678,'456789012',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5678,'567890123',2.60);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'123456789',2.00);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'124567890',3.70);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'678901234',3.30);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'789012345',3.80);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'890123456',2.90);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (5679,'901234567',3.10);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (6666,'234567890',3.10);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (6666,'567890123',3.60);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (7777,'876543210',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (7777,'890123456',3.70);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (7777,'901234567',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'124567890',3.50);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'234567890',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'345678901',3.20);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'456789012',3.40);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'567890123',2.60);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'678901234',3.30);

INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES (9876,'901234567',4.00);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As answered by Nick, the foreign key syntax needs to be fixed. There 5 foreign key declarations to change :

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty ( 
    ...
    CONSTRAINT SupervisorFK FOREIGN KEY (FacSupervisor) REFERENCES Faculty(FacNo)
);

CREATE TABLE Offering ( 
    ...
    CONSTRAINT CourseFK FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course(CourseNo),
    CONSTRAINT FacultyFK FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) REFERENCES Faculty(FacNo)
);

CREATE TABLE Enrollment( 
    ....
    CONSTRAINT OfferingFK FOREIGN KEY (OfferNo) REFERENCES Offering(OfferNo) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT StudentFK FOREIGN KEY (StdNo) REFERENCES Student(StdNo) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CONSTRAINT CourseFK FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course(CourseNo)
```

Instead of :

```
CONSTRAINT CourseFK FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course
```

---

2) When it comes to inserting data, you should expect issues when processing dates. You are giving MySQL values like `'1/Mar/2001'` for a column of datatype `date` (namely, `Faculty.FacHireDate`) : it will not accept it. The default format for dates is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

One solution is to translate the format when extracting data from Oracle, by using `TO_CHAR(FacHireDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`, or maybe by changing [NLS parameter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams143.htm). Else, you can use [MySQL function `STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to translate the string to date :

```
INSERT INTO Faculty VALUES (
    '543210987',
    'VICTORIA',
    'EMMANUEL',
    'BOTHELL',
    'WA',
    'MS',
    'PROF',
    120000.0,
    NULL,
    STR_TO_DATE('15/Apr/1998', '%d/%b/%Y'),
    '98011-2242'
);
```

---

With these fixes, the script runs fine in **[this MySQL DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/55xoEtsSgZssnsrHCRfJEk/0)**.

Comment: Thank you! I corrected all the lines as your instructions, the code works without error now.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL the definition of a foreign key constraint must include the column name as well as the table name (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)). So for example, you need to change

```
CONSTRAINT CourseFK FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course
```

to

```
CONSTRAINT CourseFK FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course(CourseNo)
```

Comment: @Steve sorry I didn't notice the further down code with the dates so I could address that too. Good to see GMB was paying more attention!

Comment: It's OK. You still pointed out a mistake which needs to correct. Thank you!